# Codeigniter - Show and Edit Last Id recorded

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, count, insert

I want to show last insert data according to packageId on package page. For example, after I edit Gold Package, System adds new data of Gold Package and showing the last insert of Gold Package on Package page. But I list data according to packageId and How can I list them according packageId? How can I edit last insert Id of Gold Package again?

Controller Package:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Package extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()

    {

        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->model('service_model');

    }

    public function index()
    {

        $this->lang->load('content', $this->session->userdata('userLang'));

        $viewData['packs'] = $this->db->get("package")->result();

        $this->load->view('package', $viewData);
    }

    public function edit($packageId)
    {

        $this->lang->load('content', $this->session->userdata('userLang'));

        $viewData['packages'] = $this->db->where("packageId", $packageId)->get("package")->result();

        $viewData['packs'] = $this->db->get("package")->result();

        $this->load->view('package_edit', $viewData);
    }

    public function update($packageId) {



        $this->lang->load('content', $this->session->userdata('people_lang'));

        $viewData['services'] = $this->service_model->update_services($packageId);

        $this->load->view('package',$viewData);

            $data = array (

                "packageEditUser" => $this->input->post("packageEditUser"),

                "packageRev" => $this->input->post("packageRev"),

                "packageNameEn" => $this->input->post("packageNameEn"),

                "packagePrice" => $this->input->post("packagePrice"),

                "packagePriceCut" => $this->input->post("packagePriceCut"),

                "packageActive" => $this->input->post("packageActive"),

                "packageEditDate" => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),

            );

            $update = $this->db->where("packageId", $packageId)->insert("package", $data);

            if($update) {

                redirect(base_url("package"));

            }else {

                echo "Hata!";

            }

    }



}
?>
```

Package View:

```
    <h1> PACKAGES </h1>
                    <p>Choose Your Special Package Plan. </p>
                </div>
                <?php foreach($packs as $get) { ?>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-3">
                    <div class="pricing-table <?php if ($get->packageNameEn == 'Platinum') { echo 'most-popular'; } ?>">
                        <div class="pricing-head">
                            <h1> <?php echo $get->packageNameEn; ?> </h1>
                            <h5><del>€ <?php echo $get->packagePrice ?></del></h5>
                            <h2><span class="note">€</span><?php echo $get->packagePriceCut ?> </h2>

                        </div>
                        <ul class="list-unstyled">
                            <li>8 hours coverage</li>
                            <li>500 digital images</li>
                            <li>100 A3 Hard Copy</li>
                            <li>Bridal portrait with 11X14</li>
                            <li>Engagement portrait with 11X14</li>
                            <li>Income Tax included</li>
                        </ul>
                        <div class="price-actions">
                            <a class="btn" href="javascript:;">Get Now</a>
                            <a class="btn" href="<?php echo base_url("package/edit/$get->packageId"); ?>">Edit</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php } ?>
```

Edit Package View:

```
<form class="cmxform form-horizontal tasi-form" id="signupForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="<?php echo base_url("package/update/$get->packageId"); ?>">

                            <?php } ?>

                            <!-- Hidden Classes -->

                            <div class="form-group" hidden>

                                <label class="col-sm-2 col-sm-2 control-label">The User Who Edit</label>

                                <div class="col-sm-10">

                                    <input type="text" name="packageEditUser" class="form-control" value="<?php  echo $this->session->userdata('people_id'); ?>" readonly>

                                </div>

                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group" hidden>

                                <label class="col-sm-2 col-sm-2 control-label">Rev Id</label>

                                <div class="col-sm-10">

                                    <?php foreach($packages as $get) { ?>

                                    <input type="text" name="packageRev" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $get->packageId; ?>" readonly>

                                    <?php } ?>

                                </div>

                            </div>

                            <!-- / Hidden Classes -->



                            <div class="form-group ">

                                <label for="username" class="control-label col-lg-2">Package Name: </label>

                                <div class="col-lg-10">

                                    <?php foreach($packages as $get) { ?>

                                        <input class=" form-control" type="text" value="<?php echo $get->packageNameEn; ?>" readonly />

                                    <?php } ?>

                                </div>

                            </div>





                            <!-- Basic select -->

                            <div class="form-group">

                                <label class="control-label col-lg-3">Package Name <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>

                                <div class="col-lg-9">

                                    <?php foreach($packages as $get) { ?>

                                        <input type="text" name="packageNameEn" class="form-control" placeholder="Package Name" value="<?php echo $get->packageNameEn; ?>">

                                    <?php }?>

                                </div>

                            </div>

                            <!-- /basic select -->

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label col-lg-2" for="inputSuccess">Services:</label>
                                <div class="col-lg-6">
                                    <div class="checkboxes">
                                        <label class="label_check" for="checkbox-01">
                                            <input name="sample-checkbox-01" id="checkbox-01" value="1" type="checkbox" /> I agree to the terms &#38; conditions.
                                        </label>
                                        <label class="label_check" for="checkbox-02">
                                            <input name="sample-checkbox-02" id="checkbox-02" value="1" type="checkbox" /> Please send me regular updates. </label>
                                        <label class="label_check" for="checkbox-03">
                                            <input name="sample-checkbox-02" id="checkbox-03" value="1" type="checkbox" /> This is nice checkbox.</label>
                                        <label class="label_check" for="checkbox-04">
                                            <input name="sample-checkbox-04" id="checkbox-04" value="1" type="checkbox" /> I agree to the terms &#38; conditions.
                                        </label>
                                        <label class="label_check" for="checkbox-05">
                                            <input name="sample-checkbox-05" id="checkbox-05" value="1" type="checkbox" /> Please send me regular updates. </label>
                                        <label class="label_check" for="checkbox-06">
                                            <input name="sample-checkbox-06" id="checkbox-06" value="1" type="checkbox" /> This is nice checkbox.</label>
                                        <label class="label_check" for="checkbox-07">
                                            <input name="sample-checkbox-07" id="checkbox-07" value="1" type="checkbox" /> I agree to the terms &#38; conditions.
                                        </label>
                                        <label class="label_check" for="checkbox-08">
                                            <input name="sample-checkbox-08" id="checkbox-08" value="1" type="checkbox" /> Please send me regular updates. </label>
                                        <label class="label_check" for="checkbox-09">
                                            <input name="sample-checkbox-09" id="checkbox-09" value="1" type="checkbox" /> This is nice checkbox.</label>
                                        <label class="label_check" for="checkbox-10">
                                            <input name="sample-checkbox-10" id="checkbox-10" value="1" type="checkbox" /> This is nice checkbox.</label>

                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">

                                <div class="col-lg-6">

                                    <h5>Package Price:</h5>

                                    <div class="input-group m-bot15">

                                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fas fa-euro"></i></span>

                                        <?php foreach($packages as $get) { ?>

                                            <input type="text" name="packagePrice" data-mask="€ 999.99" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $get->packagePrice; ?>">

                                        <?php }?>

                                    </div>

                                </div>

                                <div class="col-lg-6">

                                    <h5>Discounted Price:</h5>

                                    <div class="input-group m-bot15">

                                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fas fa-euro"></i></span>

                                        <?php foreach($packages as $get) { ?>

                                            <input type="text" name="packagePriceCut" data-mask="€ 999.99" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $get->packagePriceCut; ?>">

                                        <?php }?>

                                    </div>

                                </div>

                            </div>



                            <!-- Basic select -->

                            <div class="form-group">

                                <label class="control-label col-lg-3">Status <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>

                                <div class="col-lg-9">

                                    <select name="packageActive" class="form-control">

                                        <?php foreach($packages as $get) { ?>

                                            <option value="<?php echo $get->packageActive; ?>" readonly><?php if($get->packageActive == 1) {echo 'Active';} else {echo 'Deactive';} ?></option>

                                        <?php }?>

                                        <option value="1">Active</option>

                                        <option value="2">Deactive</option>

                                    </select>

                                </div>

                            </div>

                            <!-- /basic select -->



                            <div class="form-group">

                                <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-10">

                                    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Edit Package</button>

                                    <button class="btn btn-default" type="reset">Reset</button>

                                </div>

                            </div>

                        </form>
```

Database:

```
CREATE TABLE `package` (
  `packageId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `packageRev` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Revizyon',
  `packageNameEn` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `packageNameAr` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `packageService` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '',
  `packagePrice` decimal(6,2) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '',
  `packagePriceCut` decimal(6,2) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '',
  `packageAddUser` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '',
  `packageAddDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '',
  `packageEditUser` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `packageEditDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `packageActive` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`packageId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

Comment: if you are  showing a single record per view then u should use `row();` instead of `result()` to fetch the record from table

Comment: I want to show updating data of package. But When update I added new insert and I want to show last insert data of package. How can I show last insert Id?

Comment: use `$this->db->insert_id();` after the insert is done to get insert id, i don't know what logic u use in ur code but when updating any record use update query with where clause not insert query

Comment: How can I use this in this project? Can you show answer?

Comment: I have 3 packages such as Silver, Gold and Platinum. I want to edit these package preferences. For example,I want to add new column of Gold Package like insert when I update package. And I want to show last Gold Package edit.

Comment: do you want to show the last data inserted or also updated?

Comment: I want to both show last data and update this data.

Comment: Package View Page, I show my packages such as Silver, Gold, Platinum. And Package Edit Page which I want to edit last data of any package. Again I edit any package system automatic add new data. And I again show the last data on Package View.

Comment: so you don't want to lose the first data after edit? you want to create new data.

Comment: Yes I don't want to lose first data after edit. Yes.

Comment: you must change your update form action. it must be same as insert form action

Comment: How can I do that? Can you show me?

Comment: show me your actions of the insert and update forms

Comment: I edited my question. You can see to up.

Comment: ok. if you want to don't lost the first data after the edit. you must create I new table.  I answer it with details.

Comment: Also is it possible in the same table?

Comment: Yes, possible but maybe it shows as duplicate data.

Comment: Okay. I wait for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*If You want to don't lost data after its update. You must insert the data such new data no update and for selecting the latest updated data you must use time, create a two new column update_id, current_time. like this.*

*After that If You want to show the last data updated use `Current_time` to select that like this*

```
$this->db->order_by('Current_time','DESC');
$data = $this->db->get('comment_update',1)->result_array();
```

Comment: How can I edit this when I want to edit package? For example, I edited Gold Package. And I want to edit it again. How can I show it on Package View?

Comment: this work like the edit of the StackOverflow answers.

Comment: So for this in same table, I created packageRev Id. For example, when I edit Gold package -it has packageId 1- system automatic add packageId 1 to packageRev 1 with new insert. I think like this. Is it possible? I added to up my database.

Comment: Can you show me Package View? How can I call a new edit on Package View?

Comment: Yes.what you want to see in view? the last data updated or last data inserted?

Comment: I want to firstly, I want see both them. In future, If I will add new package, I wanna see this in package table.

Comment: May you show me controller and package page in your answer? I can not understand clearly.

Comment: the above answer is an example you must create a new table with your own column and own data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176921/discussion-between-abdulahmad-matin-and-khaoscrea).

Comment: update table is saving old data, okay. Where is saving new data?

Comment: Can you come to chat? @abdulahmad-matin

Comment: My reputation is under 20 so I can not text on chat. Your last send code is not working. Can you set your code on controller again? @AbdulAhmad Matin

Comment: @KhaosCrea now you can move to chat

Comment: You sent last code me on chat. Can you convert to controller code? Bcs it is not working in view.

Comment: replace result_array() to result()

Comment: I tried. It doesnt work already. Can you convert it controller code?

Comment: i can't. i tested the code it work for me. maybe your code have other prolem

Comment: Code have not other problem. Just i need controller code like ur view code.

Comment: move to https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176921/discussion-between-abdulahmad-matin-and-khaoscrea

Comment: Your solution is probably helped me but come to chat @AbdulAhmad Matin